# pthreads: inconsistency between gcc and icc on Linux

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

The following code produces wrong and inconsistent output with gcc (4.1.2 20080704) but correct and expected output with icc (Version 11.1) . But when I moved the thread_data_array[] definition from main() to global (immediately after the struct thread_data definition) it works fine with both compilers. I do not see why this change should make any difference. I would like to generate threads recursively so I need to call it from a function but not define as global. Could someone explain what is wrong the code please?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 4

struct thread_data {
    int  thread_id;
    int  sum;
};

/* struct thread_data thread_data_array[NUM_THREADS]; */

void *p_task(void *threadarg)
{
    struct thread_data *my_data;
    int taskid;
    int sum;

    my_data = (struct thread_data *) threadarg;
    taskid = my_data->thread_id;
    sum = my_data->sum;

    printf("Thread #%d with sum %d\n", taskid, sum);

    for ( sum = 0; sum < 000000000; sum++ ) {
        for ( taskid = 0; taskid < 000000000; taskid++ ) {
            sum+=taskid;
        }
    }

    return my_data;
}

int main ()
{
    struct thread_data thread_data_array[NUM_THREADS]; /*this does not work*/

    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    long t;

    for ( t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++ ) {
        thread_data_array[t].thread_id = t;
        thread_data_array[t].sum = (int) t*2;
        rc = pthread_create( &threads[t], NULL, p_task, (void *) &thread_data_array[t] );
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The 'problem' is not observed with gcc version 4.4.1. Could it be a bug in GCC? The earlier one was the latest from CentOS, so it makes me wonder...

Comment: Just as a minor point, all questions should have a "this is what I expect" section and a "this is actually what happens" section :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, my first thought would be that the main thread is actually exiting, and taking its stack frame with it, before the other threads are finished. From what I remember about pthreads (and this is over a decade and a half ago, using them with DCE), there's absolutely nothing special about the main thread other than the stack size.

If the array is declared global, the exit from `main` will have no effect on it but, if it's in the stack frame for `main`, I'd be very careful using it after it exits.

I'm basing this partially on guesswork since you haven't actually explained what the behavior is that you're seeing.

I would suggest inserting the following code before the `pthread_exit` in `main`:

```
for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++ )
    pthread_join (threads[t], NULL);
```

Comment: Also note that, when main() exits, the entire process gets terminated, so many of the threads may not complete.  Some might not even start.

Answer (score 1):

You destroy your stack frame before you've joined the threads using the data on the stack.

Before you call pthread_exit(), you want to call pthread_join() for each thread you created.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that when pthread_exit() is called and the thread exits, the stack for the thread is no longer valid.

You have two choices.

1. Use pthread_join() to wait for the thread to finish.
2. Dynamically allocate the thread_data array.

Comment: I thought pthread_exit would fix the problem of waiting. It didn't. I was confused as the data was valid by the time the thread was called, info was displayed, but something else happened and garbage was being printed.